# Update rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, transformation, rotations, quaternions

Imagine you have a two noded beam in space, defined by extreme nodes `1` and `2`.

[image]

Image is owned by Jean-Marc Battini.

To simplify, initially, the longitudinal axis of the beam, local `x` axis, defined by the unit vector of the line that connects the nodes `1` and `2` , is coincident with the `X` axis of the global coordinate system. I also know the original directions of local `y` and `z` axis.

Now assume that the beam rotated, with independent rotations in nodes `1` and `2`. I know the rotations along global `X`, `Y` and `Z` axis of nodes `1` and `2`.

How can I know the updated vectors that define the new local coordinate system of the beam, `x`, `y` and `z` based on the original vectors and the rotations about the global axis at each node? Or, as per figure above, how can I know the rotation matrices `Rr`, `R1` and `R2` based on the rotation matrix `R0` and rotation values of nodes `1` and `2`?

Thanks!

Comment: I think picture would be helpful.

Comment: Let $R_1(a)$ be the point where $a$ is taken by the first rotation, and $R_2(b)$ defined analogously. Isn't the beam still the straight line between $R_1(a)$ and $R_2(b)$?

Comment: Yes, but the local frame rotated with it.

Comment: The local frame can't rotate with it, because the local frame is overconstrained. If one node twists one way, and the other node twists the other way, what do you want to think of as the orientation of the beam?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This was one of the things I wanted to clarify

Comment: However, in terms of Rr, R1 and R2 matrices, how can I get them?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by $Rr$, $R0$, $R1$, $R2$, or "the rotation values of nodes 1 and 2". Once you've found the new endpoints -- and hence the local x-axis of the final transformation -- you can come up with two other arbitrary perpendicular vectors for y and z, put them into a matrix, and then solve for the relative rotation of the beam.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I'm working with finite rotations so I need to know these matrices. R0=R10=R20 is the rotation matrix that converts the global frame to the intial local frame.

Comment: Actually you can update the beam local frame based on nodal rotations: http://bigmac.mecaest.etsii.upm.es/Site/Publicaciones_files/2004Romero.pdf